# Can't install libdb5.1 and libdb5.1++ on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, apt

Can't install this package `libdb5.1` and `libdb5.1++` on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Got this error:

```
Package libdb5.1 has no installation candidate.
```

Comment: A quick scan of https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libdb5.1 shows it only available for 14.04 LTS (Trusty).  Why do you need it? It could be you're using an old version of a program (geared for 14.04) etc.

Comment: what can I install instead ?

Answer (score 2):

Usually the method below is not recommended because of security risk (really low), but your packages does not have special dependencies.

So we download these packages from Trusty and install them on Xenial manually:

```
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/d/db/libdb5.1_5.1.29-7ubuntu1_amd64.deb
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/d/db/libdb5.1++_5.1.29-7ubuntu1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libdb5.1*.deb
```

If you also need `-dev` packages you can install them too:

```
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/d/db/libdb5.1-dev_5.1.29-7ubuntu1_amd64.deb
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/d/db/libdb5.1++-dev_5.1.29-7ubuntu1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libdb5.1*-dev*.deb
```

This packages will be marked as *Obsolete and Locally created* in `aptitude`, so you can always remove them when they become unneeded.

Comment: -1 "One-shot" installs introduce a security risk since updates are not automatically installed.

Comment: User want to solve his problem, we do not talk about security here. Moreover these packages may stay in system if user upgraded from Trusty to Xenial. So your -1 is inadequate.

Comment: Indeed -1 is inadequate; this would deserve -100 but that is not possible...

Comment: Technically your are correct, but this package has very few reverse-dependencies. It is not libssl or Linux kernel. The security risk is low.